# Getting "JSONDecodeError" when loading JSON file a second time

Tags: python, json

I have a script that loads data from a JSON file when it first starts and then continues to check if the JSON file has been updated. If it has been updated it reloads the data from the JSON file.

So far the initial load works fine but when it goes to read the file again I get "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". Why am I getting this error?

**test.json**

```
{"open":0}
```

**testingFile.py**

```
import json
import time
import datetime
import os

recordedMod = os.path.getmtime('test.json')


def getJSON():
    status = ''
    funcData = ''
    doorOpen = ''
    #read json file
    with open('test.json') as myfile:
        funcData=myfile.read()
        print(funcData)
    #load json data
    status = json.loads(funcData)
    #get Door open Status
    doorOpen = status["open"]
    #close File
    myfile.close()

    return doorOpen


doorStatus = getJSON()
print(doorStatus,end='\r')

while (True):
    currentMod = os.path.getmtime('test.json')

    if currentMod>recordedMod:
        doorStatus = getJSON()
        print(doorStatus,end='\r')
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testingFile.py", line 34, in <module>
    doorStatus = getJSON()
  File "testingFile.py", line 19, in getJSON
    status = json.loads(funcData)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Update**

The JSON file is getting edited and saved from an outside source. Currently I am testing by editing the JSON file with a text editor and saving via ssh. Later the plan is to have the file be updated with node.js

**Update and Solution**

I accepted the answer that helped me find the solution but the explanation of what was causing nthe problem I was having, and solution, is that when the file is being saved from the outside source it is simultaneously being checked for. So for a split second the file is empty which throws the error. Without any form of error handling this stopped the code from running. By adding the if statement in the getJSON function, similar to the accepted answer, the program will just drop out of the function when the file is unavailable instead of stopping.

**The New Function**

```
def getJSON():
    with open('test.json') as myfile:
        funcData=myfile.read()
        if funcData:
            status = json.loads(funcData)
            doorOpen = status['open']
            return doorOpen
```

Comment: I could not reproduce. Also the with as myfile should handle closing, so not sure what happens when you close it. You probably need a sleep in that getmttime loop, or better an OS function to notify you of file changes. Additionally, you might need some sort of file locking mechanism to prevent your script from loading the text file before the change is finished. You didn't provide enough info to reproduce, but I bet something is opening the file to write the changes, then your script reads the empty file, then the changes get written to test.json

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thank you for your response and suggestions. Nothing is being written back to the JSON file. It is getting updated from outside the this script. Once the script sees it has been updated it loads the data. This reload of data is what is causing the error. I also tried adding a sleep delay to the main loop and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is correctly reporting that the json file is bad. In other words, you'd better start believing the error messages. In this case, it is an empty file, or at least funcData is empty.

Your code needs to function with bad inputs, which are reported as JSONDecodeError. I don't know why the input file is empty, but it is. The program is telling you clear as day, and you can just look at funcData to verify that it is the empty string.

If you want, the function can just return the True/False value, or return None if anything went wrong. You should handle exceptions, but it can be in the function or outside the function. Here I have written one function to handle the json file, and one function to handle the display. Since we're printing errors, I put the exception handler in the display function.

Notice in the json reader function, I used "get" to handle the case where the json was valid, but the expected data wasn't in there. And you already know that all python functions return None if they don't execute a return, so if the file is empty, it returns None instead of the JSONEncodeError.

Also I cleaned up the file change handler loop. It now does only one job:  trigger the display function when the file changes.

```
import json
import os
import time

def getJsonAttribute(filename, attribute):
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        funcData = myfile.read()
        if funcData:
            status = json.loads(funcData)
            doorStatus = status.get(attribute, None)
            return bool(doorStatus)

def displayDoor(filename):
    try:
        doorStatus = getJsonAttribute(filename, 'open')
        if doorStatus is None:
            print ('what door?')
        else:
            print ('the door is', 'open' if doorStatus else 'closed')
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print ('the door has bad json:', str(e))

recordedMod = 0.0
while (True):
    currentMod = os.path.getmtime('test.json')
    if currentMod > recordedMod:
        recordedMod = currentMod
        displayDoor('test.json')
    time.sleep(1)
```